# Codefirst Entity Framework 'IgnoreRouteInternal'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm getting this error but I searching the solution doesn't get me to the files I need. Does anyone know how I can access IgnoreRouteInternal so I can put a Not Mapped data attribute on it to make this work?

> The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection+IgnoreRouteInternal' and the type 
>   'System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions+IgnoreRouteInternal' both have the same simple name of 'IgnoreRouteInternal' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names.
>   Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't get me to the files I need"? Can't you find these two classes? Also, when/where do you get this exception?

Comment: are you using ef5 or ef6? ef6 has improved namespace detection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532202.aspx

Comment: @GertArnold They're in the source code "System.Web...." so I can't access them for debugging. I get the exception when trying to update my database.

Comment: @philsoady I'm using EF6. I can't find any duplicate simple names anywhere. Does anyone know of a method for finding these?

Comment: Again, where do you use these classes? Show the code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry Gert, I was away for a while. I can't show you the code because it only comes up when trying to build the project as part of entity framework so it's not pointing me to where the problem in my code is.